# Spring AOP pointcut is not well formed

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop, pointcut

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0':
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: **Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor]: Constructor
>   threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed:
>   expecting 'name pattern' at character position 49
>   execution(*com.idol.performers.Performer.perform(..)**

What is wrong with my pointcut? In book it says that

```
(..) // means taking any arguments
```

my xml:

```
 ...
<aop:before pointcut="execution(*com.idol.performers.Performer.perform(..))" method="takeSeats"/>
 ...
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
<aop:before pointcut="execution(* com.idol.performers.Performer.perform(..))" method="takeSeats"/>
```

The issue is that you have no space between `*` and `com.idol.performers.Performer.perform(..)`

Comment: Sometimes parsing errors can lead to obscure messages.  In this case, it thought the `*` wildcard was a part of `com.idol.performers.Performer.perform`, meaning it was expecting that type as the return type, rather than just the `*`.  Then it suggests that before it sees a '(', that it needs to have a 'name pattern' meaning the method name.  That is why the space is necessary and that is really want it was trying to say, the best way that it could.

Answer (score 2):

There should be space between * and com.idol.performers.Performer.perform(..)